# How to make Type checking work in this case? First: Not assignable. Then, type missing

Tags: angular, typescript

When I subscribe to observable -that is projected by a `BehaviourSubject` from a service- and try to assign the subscribed value to a local variable it gives me `error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'DatosAdmin'.` and `error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'DatosAdmin': nombre, nombreCorto`

I tried to make the local's variable type `localVariable: Observable but wasn't the solution.

When I `console.log()` the subscribed data, it prints the same structure as defined in my Interface. It prints {nombre: 'someName', nombreCorto: "SN"}.

final.component.ts <- Here `this.datosAdmin` complains.

```
export class InternadoFinalComponent implements OnInit {
  datosAdmin: DatosAdmin;
  constructor(private intF: InternadoFormService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.intF.adminAcumul$.subscribe(datos => (this.datosAdmin = datos));
  }
}
```

interface.ts

```
export interface DatosAdmin {
  nombre: String;
  nombreCorto: String;
}
```

datos.service.ts

```
private adminAcumul = new BehaviourSubject({})
public adminAcumul$ = this.adminAcumul.asObservable();
adminNext(datosAdmin: DatosAdmin){
  this.adminAcumul.next(datosAdmin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was writing the question I found the answer.

Instead of an interface I had to declare a `class` and in the BehaviourSubject specify the _value.

interface.ts

```
export class DatosAdmin {
  nombre: String,
  nombreCorto: String
}
```

and datos.service.ts

```
private adminAcumul = new BehaviourSubject(new DatosAdmin);
```